# How to retrieve data without page refresh in angular2 from api call if new data is pushed?

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-services

I have two tabs open one tab shows add screen for adding new todo and another tab lists the new tab. So if I add new todo from one tab and save then in another tab the newly added todo should be displayed and that too without page refresh. How to do this using angular2 ?? Someone suggessted using websocket ?? How to do or any other idea. I want to achieve live application feature.

Comment: Why not just get the to do list again?

Comment: Actually if we consider with two user operating at different region. One is viewing the list of todo's and at the same moment if another user pushes the todo then newly added todo should be displayed to first user. Else how the first user will be notified if any new todo is added...

Comment: In that case, using websockets is the best way for communicating between two different instances of the application and sending any changes.

Comment: You can also get all items at some interval of time, but that may cause performance issues depending on how many items are there and how often you would like to refresh the list.

Comment: with the Alex's idea you can storage a "systime" in your dbs each time a change happens. At some interval you check if systime had changed (it's greater that old systime value). If it'd change, you read all the list

Comment: Ok Thanks for reply everyone. What if i am using websocket ? then do i need to setup the websocket configurations on server side or frontend side ? Actually i had setup of nodejs and websocket on my server running forever to keep running the instance...Please help if any know about this... Thank you everyone..

Comment: I think you ca use socket or server sent event. Here are some links https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp , https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events

Comment: Thank you everyone for replies and help. :)